# Need help on authentication with active directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I need to implement this authentication:

On my AD network, I want to deploy a custom .net application (Unity3D/Mono) who implements an authentication who will check in which group the logged user is.

This app communicate with a windows server throught a PHP API and Wamp (apache).

What I need :

My security chief officer asks me to send from my client app to my apache server a kerberos token in order to verify in which group the user is. Thats mean that it has to be my server who will speak with my AD ans not my client app directly.

My issue :

How do I get that kerberos token in .net/c# and what do I have to do in PHP to validate that the token is a good one ? I'm lost.

In other words :

My application get the token from the current logged user, send it to my server, my server check the user's group in my AD with this token, and my server send back a response to my app in order to certifiate that the user can access to my app.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,